# Direct3D11(C++): Updating Texture coordinates in constant buffer?

Tags: c++, directx, rendering, direct3d, direct3d11

I'm trying to make a rather basic 2D Engine with Direct3D.

I made a LoadImage() function which stores all the rather static behaviour of the image in an object. (Shaders, Vertexbuffers, Samplers etc)

I am planning to do the positioning of the vertices with matrices in constant buffers.

However, I would also like to have a DrawImage() function, which would have a parameter to tell what part of the texture should be drawn (clipped), so I would have to update the texture coordinates. 
Since the vertexbuffer is already pre-defined, I wondered if there is a way to update texture coordinates via a constantbuffer that would be sent to the vertexshader?

I hope my question is clear enough, if you have any doubts look at the code below.

```
bool GameManager::GMLoadImage(Image* pImage, const char* pkcFilePath, ImageDesc* pImDesc)
{
    pImage = new Image();

    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* pColorMap = (pImage)->GetpColorMap();


/// CREATE SHADER RESOURCE VIEW (from file) ///
    HRESULT result = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileA(m_pDevice,
                                                             pkcFilePath,
                                                             0,
                                                             0,
                                                             &pColorMap,
                                                             0);
    if (FAILED(result)) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL,"Error loading ShaderResourceView from file","Error",MB_OK);
        return false;
    }


/// RECEIVE TEXTURE DESC ///
    ID3D11Resource* pColorTex;
    pColorMap->GetResource(&pColorTex);
    ((ID3D11Texture2D*)pColorTex)->GetDesc(&((pImage)->GetColorTexDesc()));
    pColorTex->Release();

/// CREATE VERTEX BUFFER ///
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC colorTexDesc = pImage->GetColorTexDesc();
    float halfWidth = static_cast<float>(colorTexDesc.Width)/2.0f;
    float halfHeight = static_cast<float>(colorTexDesc.Height)/2.0f;

    Vertex.PosTex vertices[]=
    {
        {XMFLOAT3( halfWidth, halfHeight, 1.0f ),   XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 0.0f )},
        {XMFLOAT3( halfWidth, -halfHeight, 1.0f ),  XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 1.0f )},
        {XMFLOAT3( -halfWidth, -halfHeight, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 1.0f )},

        {XMFLOAT3( -halfWidth, -halfHeight, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 1.0f )},
        {XMFLOAT3( -halfWidth, halfHeight, 1.0f ),  XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 0.0f )},
        {XMFLOAT3( halfWidth, halfHeight, 1.0f ),   XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 0.0f )}
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexDesc,sizeof(vertexDesc));
    vertexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex.PosTex)*6;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA resourceData;
    resourceData.pSysMem = vertices;

    ID3D11Buffer* pVBuffer = pImage->GetpVertexBuffer();
    result = m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&vertexDesc,&resourceData,&pVBuffer);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL,"Error Creating VBuffer","Error",MB_OK);
        return false;
    }



/// SET POINTER TO IMAGEDESC
    ImageDesc* pThisImDesc = pImage->GetpImageDesc();
    pThisImDesc = pImDesc;

    return true;
}

bool GameManager::GMDrawImage(Image* pImage, const CLIPRECT& rkClip)
{
    ImageDesc* thisImDesc = pImage->GetpImageDesc();

    if ( (thisImDesc != m_pImDesc) ) {
        m_pImDesc = thisImDesc;
        m_pContext->IASetInputLayout(m_pImDesc->pInputLayout);
        m_pContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(m_pImDesc->Topology);

        m_pContext->VSSetShader(m_pImDesc->pSolidColorVS,0,0);
        m_pContext->PSSetShader(m_pImDesc->pSolidColorPS,0,0);
        m_pContext->PSSetSamplers(0,1,&m_pImDesc->pSampler);
        m_pContext->OMSetBlendState(m_pImDesc->pBlendState,NULL,0xFFFFFFFF);
    }

    UINT stride = m_pImDesc->VertexSize;
    UINT offset = 0;
    ID3D11Buffer* pVBuffer = pImage->GetpVertexBuffer();
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* pColorMap = pImage->GetpColorMap();

    m_pContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&pVBuffer,&stride,&offset);
    m_pContext->PSSetShaderResources(0,1,&pColorMap);

    //set constant buffers?

    m_pContext->Draw(6,0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as long as your texture coordinates are hardcoded to 0.0 through 1.0 in your vertex buffer, you can use a texture transformation matrix. It's a 3x3 matrix that will transform your 2D texture coordinates.

For instance, if you want to use the bottom-right quadrant of your texture (assuming top-left is origin), you could use the following matrix:

```
0.5 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.5 0.0
0.5 0.5 1.0
```

Then, in the vertex shader, you multiply the texture coordinates by that matrix like so:

```
float3 coord = float3(In.texCoord, 1.0);
coord *= textureTransform;
Out.texCoord = coord.xy / coord.z;
```

In.texCoord and Out.texCoord being float2 input and output texture coordinates respectively.

The division by Z is optional if you are only doing affine transformations (translations, scaling, rotations and skews) so feel free to remove it if not needed.

To generalize the matrix:

```
Sx  0.0 0.0
0.0 Sy  0.0
Tx  Ty  1.0
```

Where Txy is the position of the clip area and Sxy the size of the clip area, in texture coordinates.

Comment: One question though, why do you use float3 and not float2 for a texture coordinate? Is that for the non-affine transformations you were talking about?

EDIT: Also, could you maybe tell me what datatype I should use to store the matrix in, and how to register that datatype in HLSL (yes, I'm a newbie)

Comment: The float3 is for the matrix transform. Actually, there is a small error in my code that might have confused you. The z should be initialized with 1. The datatype for your matrix is a uniform float3x3.